# How can I use a command for a row with tabularray?

Tags: tables, macros, longtable, tabularray

I want to switch from `longtable` to `tabularray` due to its more granular customization.

In `longtable` I can use a command with an argument which sets the whole row (with `&`).
However `tabularray` does not like this and throws me an error.

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{longtable} % for comparison


\newcommand{\myrow}[1]{
  Hello #1 & my name is #1 \\
}

\NewTableCommand{\myRow}[1]{
  Hello #1 & my name is #1 \\
}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtblr}{colspec={ll}}
  Hello & world \\
 % \myrow{Peter} % does not work
 % \myRow{Hans} % does not work either
\end{longtblr}


\begin{longtable}{ll}
  Hello & world \\
  \myrow{Peter}
  \myrow{Hans}
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `expand` option.

```
\begin{longtblr}[expand=\myrow]{colspec={ll}}
  Hello & world \\
 \myrow{Peter} % does not work
 \myrow{Hans} % does not work either
\end{longtblr}
```

I think only one such macro can be expanded per `table`. It must be defined with `\newcommand`, not with `\NewTableCommand`.